# Proving $E[XY\mid\mathscr G] = XE[Y\mid\mathscr G]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I found several proof of this statement in this forum but no one use strictly the definition of conditional expectation.

> Let $X,Y$ r.v on $(\Omega, \mathscr A, P)$. Let $\mathscr G$ be a sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathscr A$. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are positive and that $X$ is $\mathscr G$ measurable. Prove that $$\mathbb E[XY\mid\mathscr G] = X\mathbb E[Y\mid\mathscr G]$$

So, is it correct the following proof?

For any $\mathscr G$-measurable positive r.v. $Z$ we have 
$$ \mathbb E[XYZ] = \mathbb E\left[XZ\mathbb E[Y\mid\mathscr G]\right]=\mathbb E\left[Z\mathbb E\left[X\mathbb E[Y\mid\mathscr G]\mid\mathscr G\right]\right] = \mathbb E\left[Z\mathbb E[XY\mid\mathscr G]\right]$$

Comment: in the first step I'm just applying the definition of conditional expectation: $E[YZ]=E\big[E[Y|X]Z\big]$, for all Z belonging to the probability space of X. It does not seems to me that I'm using what I want to prove. Am I wrong?

Comment: How do you get the last equality? How did $X$ go inside the conditional expectation ?

Comment: Yes, in the last equality I had the doubt. I'm following the Jacod-Protter book and they partially complete the proof that I asked here. In the book they claim the first equality and then they affirm that: "since XE[Y|$\mathscr G$] is also $\mathscr G$ measurable, we deduce the result by another application of the definition of conditional expectation". And is indeed this last step that I'm trying to understand

Comment: As far as I can see the last step is not any simpler the the question itself, so I recommend using simple function approximation as I have done in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is not valid. For  a correct proof note that when $X$ is   a simple function measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal G$ the result follows by taking linear combinations in the definition of condition al expectation. Now you can go through the usual process (of taking limits of simple functions and  considering positive and negative parts) to prove it for any $X$ which is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal G$  such that $E|XY| <\infty$ when $Y\geq 0$. Finally you can drop the assumption $Y \geq 0$.

Comment: Could you formally show that the result can be obtained by linear combinations when X is a simple function?

Comment: @Alberto__ $E(I_A Y|\mathcal G)=I_AE(Y|\mathcal G)$ follows from the fact that both sides are measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal G$ and their integrals over any set $B \in v$ are the same. Since conditional expectation is linear we can replace $I_A$ by any finite linear combination $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_kI_{A_k}}$.